# Responsive JavaScript drop down menu problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

Based on [this tutorial over at Webdesigntuts+](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-elements/big-menus-small-screens-responsive-multi-level-navigation/), I am implementing a responsive JavaScript menu which supports sub menus / drop downs.

Unfortunately, until the orientation of the device is changed, or the browser width is altered, the sub menu / drop down system doesn't work.

Here's the JavaScript / jQuery code:

```
var ww = $(window).width();

$(document).ready(function() {

adjustMenu();

$(".nav li a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
        $(this).addClass("parent");
    };
})

$(".toggle-menu").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(".nav").toggle();
});

});

$(window).bind('resize orientationchange', function() {
    ww = $(window).width();
    adjustMenu();
});

var adjustMenu = function() {
    if (ww <= 480) {
        $(".toggle-menu").css("display", "inline-block");
        if (!$(".toggle-menu").hasClass("active")) {
            $(".nav").hide();
        } else {
            $(".nav").show();
        }
        $(".nav li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
        $(".nav li a.parent").unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
            // must be attached to anchor element to prevent bubbling
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent("li").toggleClass("hover");
        });
    } 
    else if (ww > 480) {
        $(".toggle-menu").css("display", "none");
        $(".nav").show();
        $(".nav li").removeClass("hover");
        $(".nav li a").unbind('click');
        $(".nav li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
            // must be attached to li so that mouseleave is not triggered when hover over submenu
            $(this).toggleClass('hover');
        });
    }
}
```

Here is some sample HTML:

```
 <a class="toggle-menu" href="#"><img src="/images/responsive/menu.png" alt="Menu"></a>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about/">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/url/">Menu item</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/url/">Menu item intro</a></li>
                <li><a href="/url/sub1/">Submenu item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/url/sub2/">Submenu item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/url/sub3/">Submenu item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The navigation menu is hidden to begin with until the .toggle-menu link is clicked on. Also, the sub navigation is hidden until the parent link is clicked on.

Could anyone with more experience of jQuery / JavaScript suggest any potential solutions please?

Many thanks!

Comment: your reference link has a bug it's not working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a kind of general rule (and based off experience), it's kind of wonky to process any evaluations of dimension (width, height, etc) on `document.ready`, because there's a very real chance that your page layout isn't even laid out yet, so the values of `width` and `height` on your elements may not have been evaluated yet.

Could you try putting the `adjustMenu()` call to, say, `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`?

Also, probably better to move the `var ww = $(window).width()` call into the `adjustMenu()` function itself.

### edit

```
var adjustMenu = function () {
        var ww = $window.width();
        // the rest of your adjustMenu function
    },
    $window = $(window).bind('resize orientationchange load', adjustMenu)
    ;

$(document).ready(function () {
    // your original document ready handler
    // EXCEPT for the adjustMenu() call
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the information Richard. Much appreciated. I've tried your suggestions, but I think I must be putting the code in the wrong places. Would you mind showing me what the full $(window).load() call should look like, and also how to move the var ww = $(window).width() call into the adjustMenu() function itself as you suggest? Many thanks.

Comment: @benspencer ~ updated. you just use it like how you'd use a `$(document).ready()` handler (or any jQuery event handler, for that matter).

Comment: Richard, you're a star. That works perfectly now thank you! Really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of help. :)